# swift insert/delete row that redirect to a new page

Tags: swift

I looked some tutorials on youtube on how to add/delete rows, though none of them show how to make it so that new added text redirects to a new page.
All they show is how to add the row and delete it.

Let's say, the first page you open is blank and has only an ADD button, once you add the text you want, it would add itself in the row. However you will be able to click on the row you just added and it would bring you to another page, where you can add more things, etc, etc.

Here is a quick paint image on what exactly I mean.

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uGE9T.png)

Comment: Implement `didSelectRow` and perform a segue. Or connect the segue directly to the cell.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

by using `UItableView` you can have rows. `UItableView` has delegate method `tableView didSelectRowAt`. In the method you can handle page transitions when a row is selected.

**Some useful links for how to create `UItableView`**

[UITableView – Tutorial](http://www.thomashanning.com/uitableview-tutorial-for-beginners/)

[UITableView Tutorial with Custom Cells](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FtO5QT2D_H8)